# Getting Material outline edittext height

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to add a box beside a **Material Edittext Outline** themed, but it won't match with boxline of Edittext and its bigger because of the floating label and the helper text, like the picture below I need to **get only the height of the box** to set it to another view in the layout.

[image]